# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' on Travis

Tags: angularjs, webpack, phantomjs, karma-jasmine, travis-ci

Getting this error only on travis, working fine on my local machine.
Using Karma with Webpack and gulp for angular test cases.

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../HTTPmocks/userService.mock.js in /home/travis/build/node-app/client-test-dest/factories
         @ ./client-test-dest/factories/UserFactory.spec.js 3:23-66
```

Already tried using 'path' as path.join and path.resolve. But webpack fails on local with error,

```
WARNING in ./client-test-dest/factories/UserFactory.spec.js
Critical dependencies:
9:9-84 the request of a dependency is an expression
10:9-89 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./client-test-dest/factories/UserFactory.spec.js 9:9-84 10:9-89

WARNING in ./client-test-dest/factories ^\.\/.*$
Module not found: Error: a dependency to an entry point is not allowed
 @ ./client-test-dest/factories ^\.\/.*$
```

Node: 4.4.7

Comment: Are you developing on OS X?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved!

Issue was that git was ignoring case changes for file rename.
I did a rename in previous commits and was requiring files accordingly.

Other thing: I'm using mac OS which is case-insensitive, so at some point webpack wasn't showing me any error, but travis is running with Linux. So it was causing error there.

MUST! Every developer should run: `git config core.ignorecase false`
on local. Well, I think this should be default behaviour of git to check for case-sensitive changes.

Comment: This is awesome and saved me a ton of time! Kudos. You should mark it as the answer, too.

Comment: This just saved me hours of pulling my hair out!

Comment: Already lost time on casing. but helped to save more. I am developing in Windows and travis-ci use linux. May be time to switch to AppVeyor where I get same windows environment.